# Firefox Mobile: element animated with translate3d flows out from parent container

Tags: android, css, firefox, mobile, translate3d

I have an element which I animte with translate3d transform. The parent element has `overflow: hidden`, but on Firefox Mobile 19.0.2 during animation the animated element is visible outside of the parent element.

Animating the `top` property instead of `translate3d` is working, but it's not hardware accelerated and it's not smooth enough.

It works fine on all other mobile and desktop browsers I tested on.

I guess this is a Firefox Mobile bug, but does anyone have a workaround for this?

Here is jsfiddle link for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/dioslaska/6h8qe/

The minimal test case:

HTML:

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="translate">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#cont {
    width: 50px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#translate {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#translate.a {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -60px,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -60px,0);
}

#translate div {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**UPDATE**: It looks like the problem is solved in Firefox 27.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found a workaround here:
http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/css3-transformations-showing-content-outside-overflowhidden-region-in-firefoxandroid/

Adding a `background` and `opacity: .99` to the container element seems to solve the problem.

But still no information about what causes the problem

Comment: It works without background, but great hack for Firefox. This problem was really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the opacity: .99 hack but it was causing the layout to get pushed down..

so i tried another hack which i find that worked by applying this to your style sheet:

```
* {
   outline: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I seems found a more simple solution.
Without layout damage.

If scrolling container has height a more over than device height then this issue disappearing.
It's has a different values for portrait and landscape orientation.

It's really work with Sencha Touch 2 at FF v.23 on Android 4.0.4 for me.