# firefox css3 translate on element with overflow hidden element disappears

Tags: css, firefox, transform

I have a DOM element which I translateX() to some new position.

In Firefox this element disappears as soon as the translate occurs. After a lot of debugging it seems that this happens only when the translation is applied dynamically to the element via some action, after the element is originally rendered (it doesnt happen if the css is there from page load) and only when the translateX value is greater than the element width! Also this only happens if the dom element has "overflow: hidden".

So, if I have a 200px box:

```
#box { width: 200px; overflow: hidden; }
```

If i translate to 199px, it works perfectly:

```
$('#box').css('transform', 'translateX(199px)')
```

But if I translate to 200px, the box moves to its new position and then a second later it disappears

```
$('#box').css('transform', 'translateX(200px)')
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtkmZ/3/

- Firefox only
- Only if the dom element has overflow: hidden
- Only if the translate is applied dynamically after the first render
- Only if the translateX() value is greater than the element width

This happens consistently. Any ideas on why this happening, and any workarounds? I wasn't able to find anything online. Is this a known bug?

Comment: check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405054/firefox-mobile-element-animated-with-translate3d-flows-out-from-parent-containe

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference in behavior between Mac Chrome 36.0, Safari 7.0, and Firefox 30.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related with the

[Bug 944291 - Cropping of element with css transform + animation applied, starting in Firefox 25](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=944291)

and it is fixed until version 29.